# How to put a table at the bottom of a RDLC report page?

Tags: rdlc

I have been pulling my hair for a few days on this problem. I want to keep a table at the bottom of the first report page, NO MATTER how much other content there is (less than one page or more than one page). In other words, I want the table to behave just like a footer which is set to be printed only on the first page. However, as you may all know already, tables can't be put into a page footer in RDLC report (what a pity!).

I know I can put the rest content in a rectangle and consume the white space if there is any. However, this only works when my report is less than one-page. My table will be pushed to the next page if the content length in the rectangle exceeds the rectangle length.

Btw, I'm using VS 2012. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The footer pretty much has to be a static height, hence no tables in footers. Is the table you want to output at the bottom of each page pretty small? Is it going to have relatively the same amount of records per print?

Comment: @lrb My table is about 1.5in in height with 4 columns. It's meant to be printed only on the first page. And there are two options with different contents(I set the visibility to choose one from the other)

Comment: If you have very few field to work with you could create a table with labels and rectangles in the footer based on your dataset setting the values to aggregates of your main data set. Other than that you can use report parameters for values that can be used in the footer. however, you will have to manually built the table with other elements. using